Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'. I got this error when i try to install react-native-reanimated
Here is the error description

Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.2.1
Gradle: 8.6


Task :react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
126 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 114 up-to-date
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx8192M
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.


[CXX1210] C:\Users\Veeresh\Desktop\Projects\RN-Projects\reactNativeProjects\weather\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library found


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 7s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx8192M FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'. > [CXX1210] C:\Users\Veeresh\Desktop\Projects\RN-Projects\reactNativeProjects\weather\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library found * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 7s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
I tried installing and uninstalling cmake file , but not worked and also cleaned android gradle , still getting same error
